# Is there any way to surely avoid horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following website https://teracle.github.io/cutspace-proejct/

For some reason, on mobile phones, it has horizontal scroll to the right. I have no idea why it is happening. Maybe someone can give a hint please?

Also, I'm using js animation library. Can that cause horizontal scroll?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the CSS media queries and add on the _html_ and _body_ tags the following property : `html, body {overflow-x:hidden}`
It will fix the issue

Comment: If you have elements coming in from the left and right with the animation library then that's probably causing the issue. Setting `overflow-x: hidden` on your `body` tag should get rid of it though.

Comment: One more question, please. Why on mobile navigation menu I can scroll, even though I disabled scroll using overflow hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```js
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowX = hidden;
}
```

Comment: Taking a quick look, it appears that the problem is attributable to the sections. When the underlying classes are deleted, the problem obviously disappears. I believe there is something that unites the three classes and that changes the width / margin of the content.

I believe that by digging a little on these three sections you will be able to find the problem.

`<section class="provide-space">...</section>`
`<section class="who-do-we-serve">...</section>`
`<section class="why-choose-us ">...</section>`